# Забрать данные перед переходом на следующую страницу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Код html:

```
<li class="widget uib_w_17 clonein" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-ver="0">
    <a href="#full_item">
        <span>
            Listitem
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Код js:

```
$(".groupport").click(function(){
    groupnumber = parseInt($(this).find("span").attr('id'), 10);
});
```

Атрибуты `id` -> `/цифра/` и `class` -> `groupport`
ставятся после скачивания данных с сервера, но поскольку стоит `<a href="#full_item">` то js не успевает скачать данные(`id`)

Как решить проблему?(нужно перейти но и сохранить при нажатии)

создание елементов:

```
function setgroups(groupnumbers){

$(".leftcorner").empty();
console.log(groupcount);
          console.log(groupnumbers[1]);
for (var j = 1;j<groupcount+1;j++){

        var diclone = clonegroup.clone();
        diclone.find("span").text("group"+groupnumbers[j-1]);
        diclone.find("span").attr("id",groupnumbers[j-1]);
        diclone.addClass("groupport");
        $(".leftcorner").append(diclone);

}
}
```

Comment: А в какой момент данные скачиваются? Дополните вопрос. Здесь вам тоже нужно вынести спешащий код в отдельную функцию и вызывать ее, когда данные будут готов. Это называется callback, как я уже вам говорил. Как отложить переход по ссылке вам уже написали в ответе

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".groupport").click(function(e){
    //отменяете переход
    e.preventDefault();
    //делаете то, что вам нужно

    ....

    //затем переходите по ссылке
    location.href = 'адресс_ссылки';
});
```

Comment: работает отлично, но сохраняет `undefined`

Comment: Значит, нужно проверять выполняемый перед переходом по ссылке код. Вы либо не получаете никаких данных, либо некорректно их обрабатываете перед сохранением

Comment: `groupnumber = parseInt($(this).find("span").attr('id'), 10);` какое значение у вас попадает в `parseInt()`? Оно начинается с цифры или буквы? Если второе, то parseInt() вернёт NaN, а не число

Comment: попадает значение `"17"`

Comment: но в некоторых случаях ничего не попадает

Comment: А `undefined` на выходе во всех случаях? Вообще, без полного примера кода можно очень долго гадать

Comment: в вопросе код по добавлению елементов

Answer (score 2):

если вас интересует, отправка данных на сервер, перед переходом на другую страницу или перед ее закрытием вы можете воспользоваться ивентом 'beforeunload', например:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).on('beforeunload',function() {
   //send form data
     $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: $("form").attr("action"),
        data: $("form").serializeArray()
     });
   });
});
```